# Image distance between noisy and clean images

Tags: image-processing, distance

This is what I am trying to do:

Download MNIST images:

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
SeedRandom[42];
rctraindata = RandomChoice[trainingData, 1000];
rctraindatat = 1. - Map[Flatten, Map[ImageData, rctraindata[[All, 1]]]];
```

Add Guassian noise:

```
nrctraindatat = Table[rctraindatat[[i]] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2], 784], {i, Length[rctraindatat]}];
```

Calculate the distance between clean and noisy image:

```
EuclideanDistance[rctraindatat[[1]], nrctraindatat[[1]]] (*5.82*)
```

Scale the noisy image as follows:

```
scaled = (nrctraindatat[[1]]-Min[Flatten[nrctraindatat]])/(Max[Flatten[nrctraindatat]] - 
     Min[Flatten[nrctraindatat]]);
```

The idea behind scaling is that the clean images are within (0,1) and I wanted the noisy image to be in the same range to calculate the distance between them.
Calculate the distance again:

```
EuclideanDistance[rctraindatat[[1]], scaled] (*8.78*)
```

Which is the correct way to calculate the distance between a corrupted and a clean image and why? PSNR and SSIM are usually used as metrics. Do I need to rescale the noisy image before calculating PSNR or SSIM?

Comment: Rescaling the way you do seems wrong, since a noise outlier at one image point completely changes the rescaled image globally. But the trouble starts before that: If $[0,1]$ is the natural interval for data, what sense does it make to model noise using naive addition? If an image point has value $1$, and there is $0.3$ noise, what does the calculation $1+0.3 = 1.3$ mean? It may be a wrong model for various reasons. An amateurish fix would be to model noise using something like `addnoise[x_,noise_] := 1/Pi*ArcTan[Tan[Pi/2*(2*x-1)]+noise]+1/2`, which maps $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: A function you might find useful in the future is `Rescale`. eg `foo = Rescale[nrctraindatat[[1]], MinMax@Flatten@nrctraindatat];` then `foo === scaled (*True*)`

Comment: related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30091/60568 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159735/60568

Comment: Possibly a dumb question, but would it make sense to use `CosineDistance` for this?

Comment: Also why aren't you just using Mathematica's built-in `ImageDistance` ? You also have `RandomImage` and `ImageAdd` so you don't need to use `ImageData`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a machine learning expert but it looks like the issue could be related to how you are standardizing your noisy data, which changes the `Mean` and `StandardDeviation` of the data. Furthermore the amount of noise you are adding (`0.2`), relative to how much noise the data has `StandardDeviation@Flatten@rctraindatat (*0.31*)` seems high.

To preserve the boundaries of the data `(0,1)` I would `Clip` the data after adding noise.

```
SeedRandom[42];

(*get data*)
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];

(*make training data*)
$trainingDataSampleSize = 1000
rctraindata = RandomChoice[trainingData, $trainingDataSampleSize];
rctraindatat = 1. - Map[Flatten, Map[ImageData, rctraindata[[All, 1]]]];

(* make noisy data sets*)
noise = With[
   {
    pixelLength = Length[rctraindatat[[1]]],
    sampleSize = $trainingDataSampleSize,
    noiseMean = 0,
    noiseStandardDeviation = (StandardDeviation@Flatten@rctraindatat)/ 10

   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[noiseMean,noiseStandardDeviation], {sampleSize, pixelLength}] (* faster than Table*)
   ];

noisyData = rctraindatat + noise;
clippedData = Clip[noisyData, {0, 1}];
scaledData = (noisyData - 
     Min[Flatten[noisyData]])/(Max[Flatten[noisyData]] - 
     Min[Flatten[noisyData]]);


Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation, MinMax}[Flatten@rctraindatat]] 
(*{0.130405, 0.307826, {0., 1.}}*)

Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation, MinMax}[Flatten@noisyData]]
(*{0.130386, 0.309359, {-0.151885, 1.11268}}*)

Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation, MinMax}[Flatten@clippedData]]
(*{0.139699, 0.302406, {0., 1.}}*)

Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation, MinMax}[Flatten@scaledData]]
(*{0.223216, 0.244637, {0., 1.}}*)
```